# Color specification in plots

Tags: r

I'm playing with the ROC function in the Epi package, whose documentation specifies that you can pass graphical parameters to the plot function. By default, ROC produces a grayscale graph. I'm trying to color only the ROC curve itself (the jagged line) red.

Here's what I tried:

```
    x = rnorm(100)
    y = c(rep(0,50), rep(1,50))

    library(Epi)

    par(col="red"); ROC(form = y~x, plot="ROC")
```

This creates a strange graph with inconsistent coloring. The par documentation does describe some specific methods like col.lab and col.axis to color specific graphical elements, but doesn't include a parameter for the main line color.

I have to think this basic question must have been addressed elsewhere, but so far haven't had luck searching the R documentation and Google.

Comment: From glancing at the code in `ROC` it looks like you can't do this directly. The arguments in `...` are passed on to `plot(type = 'n',...)` and all the lines drawing is done separately with the colors hard coded.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to manually override those hard-coded elements of the function? Sorry, minimal programming experience here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case, if you want to modify the function `ROC` to suit your needs, you can do the following. Type `ROC` at the console to see the code for `ROC`. Copy and paste it into a file and assign it a new name, like `ROC2`. Look for the following code:

```
if (any(!is.na(match("ROC", toupper(plot))))) {
        plot(1 - res[, 2], res[, 1], xlim = 0:1, xlab = "1-Specificity", 
            ylim = 0:1, ylab = "Sensitivity", type = "n", ...)
        if (is.numeric(grid)) 
            abline(h = grid/100, v = grid/100, col = gray(0.9))
        abline(0, 1, col = gray(0.4))
        box()
        lines(1 - res[, 2], res[, 1], lwd = lwd)
```

You'll want to pass `col = "red"`, or some such, in the `lines` call. For instance you could add a `mycol` argument to the function itself and then change that one line to:

```
lines(1 - res[, 2], res[, 1], lwd = lwd, col = mycol)
```

Also, as I noted below, you will also have to change all instances of `ROC.tic` to `Epi:::ROC.tic`.

Comment: Not familiar with this function, but could you just add the ellipses to the `lines()` call to ensure that any graphical parameters are included in that method?

Comment: @JeffAllen Possibly, I just thought this would be simpler to understand. But it's moot as now that I try this, it appears that `ROC` is calling an un-exported function from **Epi** anyway, so more modifications will be necessary.

Comment: Thank you joran!! Works perfectly.